# Checking if a subenvironment is unique inside an enviroment

Tags: macros, environments

I would like to define a environment inside another environment, but I need to make sure the new environment is unique, so there can only be of them. 
The `unique` environment should also be able to be any point of the outlaying environment. 
So the code would be something like:

```
\begin{myenv}
    \begin{env} ... \end{env}
    \begin{env} ... \end{env}
    \begin{unique-env} 
       there can be no other environments of this type in myenv
    \end{unique-env}
    \begin{env} ... \end{env}
\end{myenv}
```

I have found out how to check that the `unique` environment exists inside `myenv`, but not how I can make sure it is the only one of this kind.

I will try to clarify a bit. I need this to be legal:

```
\begin{some_env} 
  \begin{unique-env} 
    Something 
  \end{unique-env} 
\end{some_env}
```

And this to be illegal:

```
\begin{some_env} 
  \begin{unique-env} 
    Something 
  \end{unique-env} 
  \begin{unique-env} 
    Something 
  \end{unique-env} 
\end{some_env}
```

Where the some_env is also something I have defined.

What I need to be unique doesn't need to be a environment, it could also be a command

```
\begin{some_env} 
  \uniquesCommand{Something}
\end{some_env}
```

Comment: I don't understand. So you can have only *one* `unique-env` inside `myenv`? Or if you have `unique-env`, you can't have any other environments?

Comment: @Werner I have tried clarifying it a bit now, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use a new counter that is checked at the start-up code of the environment. If the counter is equal to zero, all is fine, increase the counter to indicate that is zero not any longer, if the counter is not zero right from the start (because it has been increased already) issue an error message.

At the end of the environment the counter is reset to zero.

A counter has the advantage that it's global, it survives the end of the group (established due to the environment). One could use something like  `\ifisinside` statement too, if `\global\isinsidetrue` is applied.

Of course, it's no failsafe method -- a manual modification of the `uniquenv` counter will either allow nested `uniquenv` or disallow even the first usage of the environment, depending on the manipulation.

Note: The document below 'fails' by design here!!!!

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcounter{uniquenv}
\newenvironment{uniquenv}{%
  \ifnum\value{uniquenv} = 0 
  \stepcounter{uniquenv}%
  \else
        \GenericError{Error}{nested unique env}{You can't use a nested unique env^^J
Remove all env except the outer one!}{}
  \fi
}{%
  \setcounter{uniquenv}{0}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{uniquenv}
    Foo
  \end{uniquenv}

  \begin{uniquenv}
  \begin{uniquenv}
    Foo inside
  \end{uniquenv}
  \end{uniquenv}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Update** No reuse within `someenv`:

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcounter{uniquenv}



\newenvironment{someenv}{}{}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginDocument{someenv}{\setcounter{uniquenv}{0}}


\newenvironment{uniquenv}{%
  \ifnum\value{uniquenv} = 0 
  \stepcounter{uniquenv}%
  \else
        \GenericError{Error}{nested unique env}{You can't use a nested unique env^^J
Remove all env except the outer one!}{}
  \fi
}{%
}



\begin{document}

\begin{someenv}
  \begin{uniquenv}
    Something
  \end{uniquenv}
\end{someenv}


\begin{someenv}
  \begin{uniquenv}
    Something
  \end{uniquenv}

  \begin{uniquenv}
    Something more
  \end{uniquenv}
\end{someenv}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems almost like what I need. But I need this to be legal:

     `\begin{some_env}
           \begin{unique-env}
                 Something
           \end{unique-env}
      \end{some_env}`

And this to be illegal:

     `\begin{some_env}
           \begin{unique-env}
                 Something
           \end{unique-env}
           \begin{unique-env}
                 Something more
           \end{unique-env}
      \end{some_env}`

Where the some_env is also something I have defined.

Comment: @mallereik: What do you mean? Legal?

Comment: Sorry, my first comment, so I didn't know hitting enter would post it. @ChristianHupfer

Comment: @mallereik: See the update at the bottom of my answer please

Comment: I got it working by modifying your second suggestion.

Comment: @mallereik: Well, whatever you modified then... I don't have your `someenv` or `uniquenv` at hand, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newenvironment{myenv}
  {\global\uniqueenvfalse
   \BeforeBeginEnvironment{unique-env}{\ifuniqueenv\errmessage{ONLY ONE}\fi}
   something at startup\par}
  {\par something at end}

\newenvironment{unique-env}
  {\par\global\uniqueenvtrue}
  {\par}

\newif\ifuniqueenv

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}

Text

\begin{unique-env}
This should appear only once inside \texttt{myenv}
\end{unique-env}

Other text

\begin{unique-env}
This should appear only once inside \texttt{myenv}
\end{unique-env}

Other text

\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

This produces

```
! ONLY ONE.
\@beforebegin@unique-env@hook ...essage {ONLY ONE}
                                                  \fi 
l.28 \begin{unique-env}

?
```